# How to split the billion or million

Tags: java

I am looking for an algorithm which splits the input number to number of millions.
I tried a number of ways, but nothing worked.

**Examples:**

If the input number is 51000000 and my lot size is 50 million, then i want an output as 2.

If 110 million, then it would be 50+50+10 which means output as 3.

Comment: Luck has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Already mentioned tried different ways final int numOfLots = (int) Math.ceil(51000000 / 50000000);

Comment: It's meaningless to say "I tried different ways" if you don't mention *which* ways you tried. We're not mind readers.

Comment: yeah, understand , please close this question

Answer (score 3):

This formula can be used if the input numbers are small enough not to cause overflow:

```
number_of_chunk = (all_number + chunk_size - 1) / chunk_size
```

this division is integer division and the result is truncated to zero.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.ceil(110000000.0/*input number*/ / 50000000 /*lot size*/)` etc. would do it.

Note that I've added `.0` to one of the numbers to defeat **integer division**.

`ceil` always rounds to the next whole number.

Comment: I think your use of block comments is making your code look needlessly confusing.

Comment: tried already final int numOfLots = (int) Math.ceil(51000000 / 50000000);

Comment: Oops. Don't forget to promote one of the numbers to floating point!!! I've amended this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code you could use:

```
final int lotSize = 50;
double input = 110000000;
int result = (int)((input / 1000000.0) / lotSize + 1);
```

Obviously replace the lotSize and input variables to whatever you need. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @tengmesk , Above solution not works for 100 million double input = 100000000;